# AMP Form - multiple submit buttons

Tags: amp-html

How to set up multiple submit buttons in amp-form?

Usually the submit buttons are submitted by clicking.
In AMP there are missing (not all and not the clicked one).

I want to decide how to use data in the PHP script (and this cant be change because of core functions of the system).

```
<input type="submit" name="button1">
<input type="submit" name="button2">
```

In PHP it will looks like

```
if(isset($_POST['button1'])) { .. }
elseif(isset($_POST['button2'])) { .. }
```

But in amp-form the clicked buttons is missing (so this is not working)

Comment: [AMP-Forms](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-form) can use <input type="submit"
        value="Subscribe"> . What do you mean?

Comment: Yes but if you add the attribute name - in normal forms it will be sended when clicked, but not in amp.

if i have `<input type="text" name="test" value="1"><input type="button" name="submitBtn" value="2">test it</input>` i will only get: `$_POST['test']` but not the input `$_POST['submitBtn']` => so i cant differ what button the user clicked

Answer (score 0):

I solved it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Vergleichsliste" id="setVergleichsliste" on="change:buy_form.submit" />
<label for="setVergleichsliste">Vergleichsliste!</label>
```

Solution: Create a checkbox (will only be submitted if checked) with an on change. The label should be the button than (working). Of course: hide your checkbox for the users..